# How to activate an animation when a certain button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, dom-events

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button">Start Game</button>
  <img src="https://www.chelanfresh.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/apple.png" id="apple">

</body>
</html>
```

```css
#button {
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    color: #313133;
    }

#apple {
    height: 38%;
    width: 10%;
    margin-top: 27%;
    margin-left: 19%;
    visibility: hidden;
    animation-name: appleSlide;
    animation-duration: 3s; 
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-delay: 1s; 
}

@keyframes appleSlide {
    0% {margin-left: -50%;}
    100% {margin-left: 19%}
}
```

```js
let apple = document.getElementById("apple")
let button = document.getElementById("button")

function activateAnimations() {
    apple.style.animationPlayState = "running";
    apple.style.visibility = "visible";
  }

button.addEventListener("click", activateAnimations)
```

What my animation is it basically starts off hidden or invisible but once the user clicks on the button a picture would show up and slide to a specific position. Ive been fiddling around with animationPlayState to no avail and the animation never activates.

Comment: I think you meant `button.addEventListener("click", activateAnimations)`

Comment: gotcha, will edit the original

Answer (score 2):

1. There are a few things in your code that don't really make sense (for example `apple.document.getElementById`).
2. You should add the original position of the apple to the element (not only to the animate keyframe).
3. The button doesn't have the `activateAnimations` event.

Here is a fix for your code:

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let apple = document.getElementById("apple")
  let button = document.getElementById("button")

  function activateAnimations() {
      apple.style.animationPlayState = "running";
      apple.style.visibility = "visible";
    }

  button.addEventListener("click", activateAnimations)
});
```

```css
#button {
    min-width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    color: #313133;
    }

#apple {
    height: 38%;
    width: 10%;
    margin-top: 27%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    visibility: hidden;
    animation-name: appleSlide;
    animation-duration: 3s; 
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-delay: 1s; 
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes appleSlide {
    0% {margin-left: -50%;}
    100% {margin-left: 19%}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button">Start Game</button>
  <img src="https://www.chelanfresh.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/apple.png" id="apple">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks this worked for me! But just curious how the "load" function works. Is it waiting for all the elements to load on the page? I dont really get why using click wouldn't work in its place

Comment: before the entire page is loaded - the "apple" and the "button" elements doesn't exists so you can't access them (and you can't attach the click event to them).